# sql query shows error by changing alias name

Tags: sql, mysql, alias

```
mysql> SELECT 'STATUS', 
              status 
       FROM (SELECT ujm.user_id AS userId, 
                    ujm.job_id AS jobId, 
                    ujm.job_run_name AS jobRunName, 
                    j.response_payload -> '$.isSuccessful' AS isSuccessful, 
                    j.response_payload -> '$.error' AS errors, 
                    j.response_payload -> '$.destinationDetails' AS destinationDetails, 
                    s.name AS statusType 
             FROM user_job_mappings ujm 
             JOIN jobs j ON ujm.job_id = j.id AND j.is_deleted = 0 
             JOIN status_types s ON j.status_type_id = s.id AND s.is_deleted = 0 
             WHERE ujm.user_id = 24301 
             AND ujm.is_deleted = 0 
             order by ujm.job_id limit 1 offset 0
             ) jobs_data\G
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'status' in 'field list'

```
mysql>  SELECT 'STATUS', 
                status 
        FROM ( SELECT ujm.user_id AS userId, 
                      ujm.job_id AS jobId, 
                      ujm.job_run_name AS jobRunName, 
                      j.response_payload -> '$.isSuccessful' AS isSuccessful, 
                      j.response_payload -> '$.error' AS error, 
                      j.response_payload -> '$.destinationDetails' AS destinationDetails, 
                      s.name AS status 
                FROM user_job_mappings ujm 
                JOIN jobs j ON ujm.job_id = j.id AND j.is_deleted = 0 
                JOIN status_types s ON j.status_type_id = s.id AND s.is_deleted = 0 
                WHERE ujm.user_id = 24301 
                AND ujm.is_deleted = 0 limit 1 offset 0
               ) jobs_data\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
STATUS: STATUS
status: SUCCESSFUL
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have this two queries .
The only difference in both queries is the alias name use for status in inner query but one is giving error I don't understand why ?

Comment: Please make the effort to format your post with readable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you nest queries, the original table and column names from the inner query **no longer matter** in the outer query.

So, in this code, `status` is not just an alias anymore for the outer query. It is now the *actual column name*.

Answer (score 1):

> The only difference in both queries is the alias name use for status
> in inner query but one is giving error I don't understand why ?

That is the issue. You might see it as just alias name , but those are two different columns names for the outer query.

The outer query is looking for the status column which doesn't exists.

`statusType` <> `status`